# Problems Setting up constraints in IOS8 with Swift and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have tried for several hours to design and place the different elements accordingly. But it seems like no matter what I do, the elements get messed up with sizes and location when moving to different device (screen sizes).
How would you place constraints in the screen below to ensure proper scaling and position when moving to a different device?
http://postimg.org/image/hl4incjzh/

I only work in portait mode.
The views at the left is a UIImage view and a UIWebview which is hidden, and will show dynamically based on external content.
Label and the textview below is also dynamically populated on ViewDidLoad.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: I might say that I'm using AutoLayout and sizeclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on a view element and use the add-constraints-menu:

There you can set different size-options like the margin, if the view should resize etc.

[image]